# Update rest of data in codeigniter import xls file

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Help me please how to check last insert id and import rest of data ignoring previous data. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code to find last insert id

```
$this->db->insert($this->tablename, $details);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```